# How does the serverless datadog forwarder encrypt/encode their logs?

Tags: aws-lambda, datadog

I am having trouble figuring out how the datadog forward encodes/encrypts its messages from the datadog forwarder. We are utilizing the forwarder on datadog using the following documentation: https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/forwarder/ . On that page there, Datadog has an option to send the same event to another lambda that it invokes via the AdditionalTargetLambdaARNs flag. We are doing this and having the other lambda invoke but the event input that we are getting is long string that looks like it is base64 encoded but when I put it into a base64 decoder, I get gibberish back. I was wondering if anyone knew how datadog is compressing/encoding/encrypting their data/logs that they send so that I can read the logs in my lambda and be able to preform actions off of the data being forwarded? I have been searching google and the datadog site for documentation on this but I can't find any.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Datadog uses zstd compression in order to compress its data before sending it: https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/blob/972c4caf3e6bc7fa877c4a761122aef88e748b48/pkg/util/compression/zlib.go